# ASP.NET: Load ListItem collection to Footer template DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm not able to populate a dropdownlist of a footer template field in a GridView, what I do is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor Country" SortExpression="VENDOR_COUNTRY">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox21" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VENDOR_COUNTRY") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label37" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VENDOR_COUNTRY") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddVendorCountry" runat="server" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" Font-Size="Small">
                                           </asp:DropDownList>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then I have a function in the code behind to get the list of listitems (I will use it three times):

```
  Public Function GetCountries() As List(Of ListItem)

        Dim countryList As New List(Of ListItem)
        countryList.Add(New ListItem("AF", "AF"))
        countryList.Add(New ListItem("AX", "AX"))
        (...)
  End Function
```

I tried to load it in the Page_Load, gridview RowDataBound, gridview DataBound events... unsuccessfuly:

```
 Protected Sub gvData_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvData.DataBound
    Dim ddlCountries As DropDownList = TryCast(gvData.FooterRow.FindControl("ddVendorCountry"), DropDownList)
    ddlCountries.DataSource = GetCountries()
    ddlCountries.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I used to work with the MVC pattern using Razor but now I have to rescue an old webpage and despite is within the .NET platform I'm lost...

Thank you for your advices

Comment: It should work in several events: `RowCreated`, `RowDataBound`, `DataBound`, `PreRender`. What problem do you see exactly? You cannot access the DropDownList?

Comment: No error shown, just an empty dropdownlist